# Return various sum totals of integer list

Tags: python, list, sum

Is there a way to return various sums of a list of integers? Pythonic or otherwise.

For e.g. various sum totals from `[1, 2, 3, 4]` would produce `1+2=3, 1+3=4, 1+4=5, 2+3=5, 2+4=6, 3+4=7`. Integers to be summed could by default be stuck to two integers only or more I guess.

Can't seem to wrap my head around how to tackle this and can't seem to find an example or explanation on the internet as they all lead to "Sum even/odd numbers in list" and other different problems.

Comment: As in if someone wanted to add 3 integers together they could. I'm on a problem with only two integers being added but maybe in some scenarios there would be a problem for adding 3 integers together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
from itertools import combinations

li = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# assuming we don't need to sum the entire list or single numbers,
# and that x + y is the same as y + x
for sum_size in range(2, len(li)): 
    for comb in combinations(li, sum_size):
        print(comb, sum(comb))
```

outputs

```
(1, 2) 3
(1, 3) 4
(1, 4) 5
(2, 3) 5
(2, 4) 6
(3, 4) 7
(1, 2, 3) 6
(1, 2, 4) 7
(1, 3, 4) 8
(2, 3, 4) 9
```

Comment: For clarity/elaboration, maybe change the range to be range(1, len(li) + 1) even if those are trivial combinations.

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren that is exactly why that `#` exists

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for ?
`A=[1,2,3,4] for i in A: for j in A: if i!=j: print(i+j)`